# Allowing arrow key navigation/enter functionality to autosuggest box

Tags: jquery, navigation, autosuggest, arrow-keys

Im learning how to implement an autosuggest box and I just cant figure out how to make the results accessable with the arrow keys and enter button. I really have no idea how I would go about doing this. I already have it so when I click on the box the results move to the input field, but now I want to make the results accessable with the arrow keys and when you click enter it will move that item to the input field.
Heres my code:

```
    <div class="input-wrapper">
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" value="Type in a city or town" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" > <input type="submit" value="Search">

<div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="result"></ul>


</div>
</div>
```

And script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
var search_term = $(this).attr('value');

$.post('php/search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);

$('.result li').click(function(){
    var result_value = $(this).text();
    $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
    $('.result').html('');

    });

    });

});
     });
     function onBlur(el) { 
    if (el.value == '') { 
      el.value = el.defaultValue; 
    } 
    } 
   function onFocus(el) { 
      if (el.value == el.defaultValue) { 
       el.value = ''; 
    } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        // yourcode
    }
});
```